# When sending the form, why is the value undefined?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a form

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" ([ngModel])="login" placeholder="Login" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" ([ngModel])="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button (click)="logUpUser()"  class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and I want to send the value from HTML form to the typescript method

```
export class LogUpFormComponent implements OnInit {
    login: string;
    password: string;

    constructor() { }

    logUpUser() {
      console.log(this.login);
    }
}
```

but in the method `logUpUser()` I get the value of undefined. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `[(ngModel)]` not `([ngModel])`

Comment: It's the _banana in a box_ syntax. Maybe this will help you remember. ;-)

Comment: thank you, but after that I have such an error `If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions` and after adding the attribute `name` error is not resolved

Comment: Adding the name attribute certainly should resolve it... Can you add the iinput` tag's HTML now that you've added the name property?

Comment: after adding the input should look like this? `<input [(ngModel)]="login" name="l" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" required>` after that the error is not resolved

Comment: Did you add a name property to both of the inputs?

Comment: oh thank you very much !!! just a bug showing in the same line where I added the attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct HTML-Code has to look like this:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="login" placeholder="Login" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button (click)="logUpUser()"  class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And in your ts-File try this:

```
login: string = '';
password: string = '';
```

Comment: thank you, but after that I still get it undefined... maybe I have some mistake in typescript?

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to give both variables an initial value orherwise the binding fails. Please, try it out.